# How to revert to factory settings?

Tags: restore, reinstall

I want to reverse all my Ubuntu modifications and return the system to factory settings. I've installed useless stuff and now I want to uninstall everything I manually installed/factory reset.. Is there a way to do that?

I read this article, [Reinstall Ubuntu from command line](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/reinstall-ubuntu-from-command-line.html), and it told me to run this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
```

Then this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But Ubuntu can't figure out even what the first one means. It tells me `unknown option -a`. If you have another way of reinstalling Ubuntu to factory settings I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to "reset" Ubuntu. *You can't even do that on Windows 7 unless there is an OEM-provided recovery partition...*

---

Just burn the latest ISO to a DVD and reinstall.

Easiest way, plus you'll get 16.04's new features :)

Comment: Wait your telling me to uninstall 15.10 and install 16.04 ? And what new feautures does it have exactly?

Comment: @Dsafds - You can completely overwrite 15.10 during the 16.04 install. One new feature is being able to move the dock to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hm ok.. i think ima just install ubuntu 16.04(which i didnt know came out).. and then remove ubuntu 15.04 from my vmware... i use ubuntu for dev purposes

Answer (score 3):

Recently there is appeared a new tool to get this. Its name is Resetter, and you can find it [here on Github](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter).

With Resetter you can completely clean up your system or choose what you want to remove.

How to install (nowadays) it's via the newest deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i resetter_0.0.?-beta_all.deb
```

Then you can run it directly:

```
resetter
```

And now choose *Automatic Reset* or *Custom Reset*. You'll be asked for a new administrator user and password (don't forget it)

Comment: Please share the instruction to install and use. Also notice that it is still in early beta stage. So it should be used with caution